# Configure SSL and ACLs for kafka-console-consumer

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I am adding SSL security to my Confluent-3.0.1 Kafka Cluster following the instructions [here](http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/ssl.html) and [here](http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authorization.html).

In the Linux transaction snippets below, I have replaced my server names with myserverA, myserverB and myserverC. I also obscured passwords. This is my first posting on a message board. I apologize for any poorly formatted sections of this post.

My questions:

What ACL controls the access to fetch offsets shown just below?
Do I need to change my configuration or SSL keys?

Many thanks for any assistance you may be able to provide.

I was able to produce data using the kafka-console-producer over SSL, but can not read the data using the kafka-console-consumer. I receive the following error:

```
[kafka@myserverA confluent-3.0.1]$ /kafka/confluent-3.0.1/bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server myserverA:9093 --zookeeper myserverA:2181/kafka --topic ssl-test --from-beginning --new-consumer --consumer.config /kafka/data/client/ssl/client.properties
[2017-06-27 13:11:50,462] WARN Attempt to fetch offsets for partition ssl-test-0 failed due to: Not authorized to access topics: [Topic authorization failed.] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher)
[2017-06-27 13:11:50,473] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 6 : {ssl-test=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-06-27 13:11:50,476] ERROR Unknown error when running consumer:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [ssl-test]
```

It is not clear if my problem is in the client configuration, or the inter-broker configuration.

The server.properties file on each of my three brokers includes the following:

```
###################### SSL Configuration ################
#
ssl.keystore.location=/kafka/data/ssl/keystore/kafka.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=<hidden for this posting>
ssl.key.password=<hidden for this posting>
ssl.truststore.location=/kafka/data/ssl/truststore/kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=<hidden for this posting>

ssl.client.auth=requested
#ssl.cipher.suites=
ssl.enabled.protocols = TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.truststore.type = JKS

security.inter.broker.protocol=ssl

# #### Enable ACLs ####
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true

super.users=User:CN=myserverA,OU=NBCUniversal,O=NBCUniversal,L=NY,ST=NY,C=US;User:myserverB,OU=NBCUniversal,O=NBCUniversal,L=NY,ST=NY,C=US;User:CN=myserverC,OU=NBCUniversal,O=NBCUniversal,L=NY,ST=NY,C=US
```

I use the same client.properties for the producer.config and consumer.config. It contains the following:

```
###################### SSL Configuration ################
#
security.protocol=ssl

ssl.keystore.location=/kafka/data/client/ssl/keystore/kafka.client.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=<hidden for this posting>
ssl.key.password=<hidden for this posting>
ssl.truststore.location=/kafka/data/client/ssl/truststore/kafka.client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=<hidden for this posting>

#ssl.provider=
#ssl.cipher.suites=
ssl.enabled.protocols = TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
```

I have a large number of ACL grants on the ssl-test topic. I have tried: 1)SSL Dnames with spaces after commas, 2) SSL Dnames with no spaces after commas, 3) SSL Common Names for broker certs

```
[root@myserverA ~]# /kafka/confluent-3.0.1/bin/kafka-acls --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=myserverA:2181/kafka --list --topic ssl-test
Current ACLs for resource `Topic:ssl-test`:
User:CN=Test Client,OU=Test Client Unit,O=Test Client Org,L=LA,ST=CA,C=US has Allow permission for operations: Read from hosts: *
User:CN=Test Client, OU=Test Client Unit, O=Test Client Org, L=LA, ST=CA, C=US has Allow permission for operations: Read from hosts: *
User:myserverA has Allow permission for operations: Write from hosts: *
User:myserverC has Allow permission for operations: Read from hosts: *
User:CN=myserverB,OU=NBCUniversal,O=NBCUniversal,L=NY,ST=NY,C=US has Allow permission for operations: Write from hosts: *
User:CN=myserverA,OU=NBCUniversal,O=NBCUniversal,L=NY,ST=NY,C=US has Allow permission for operations: Read from hosts: *
User:Test Client has Allow permission for operations: Read from hosts: *
User:Test Client has Allow permission for operations: Write from hosts: *
User:myserverB has Allow permission for operations: Write from hosts: *
User:CN=Test Client,OU=Test Client Unit,O=Test Client Org,L=LA,ST=CA,C=US has Allow permission for operations: Write from hosts: *
User:CN=myserverC,OU=NBCUniversal,O=NBCUniversal,L=NY,ST=NY,C=US has Allow permission for operations: Read from hosts: *
User:CN=myserverA,OU=NBCUniversal,O=NBCUniversal,L=NY,ST=NY,C=US has Allow permission for operations: Write from hosts: *
User:CN=myserverB,OU=NBCUniversal,O=NBCUniversal,L=NY,ST=NY,C=US has Allow permission for operations: Read from hosts: *
User:myserverB has Allow permission for operations: Read from hosts: *
User:myserverA has Allow permission for operations: Read from hosts: *
User:CN=Test Client, OU=Test Client Unit, O=Test Client Org, L=LA, ST=CA, C=US has Allow permission for operations: Write from hosts: *
 ser:myserverC has Allow permission for operations: Write from hosts: *
 ser:CN=myserverC,OU=NBCUniversal,O=NBCUniversal,L=NY,ST=NY,C=US has Allow permission for operations: Write from hosts: *
```

The kafka-console-producer functions normally through SSL:

```
[kafka@myserverA confluent-3.0.1]$ bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list myserverA:9093 --topic ssl-test --producer.config /kafka/data/client/ssl/client.properties
j
k
<Ctrl-D>
```

Comment: Per [the documentation](http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authorization.html#common-cases), to consume you need READ access on the topic *and the group*. While you've given the ACLs for the topic in your post, you've not said if there are any ACLs for the consumer group.

Comment: Also, by default the usernames are SSL names *without* spaces. You can customize this though, see http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authorization.html#further-configuration

Comment: Hi @tombentley, excellent suggestion. It was my understanding that the --new-consumer argument automatically created the group and granted access. However, I added group.id=ssl-test-group to my client.properties and included the client cert in a group ACL:

Comment: This produced the same response.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz_examples) the consumer needs both READ *and* DESCRIBE on the topic, as well as the consumer groups needing READ. The option `--consumer` can be used as a convenience to set all of these as once; using their example:

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 \
  --add \
  --allow-principal User:Bob \
  --consumer \
  --topic Test-topic \
  --group Group-1
```

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple issues in my Kafka SSL configuration. However, the explicit error "WARN Attempt to fetch offsets for partition ssl-test-0 failed..." while running kafka-console-consumer was due to the fact that the Client Certificate was not included in the truststore for kafka node B and C.